# Error using resizebox and tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need a hand with scaling a `tikz` generated picture.

I have an example of using `tikz` I found in one of the websites (not my own work). I am trying to scale and fit it into a6 layout. I read library `graphics` defines two commands `resizebox{}{}{}` and `scalebox{}{}`, which apparently `tikz` also includes. However, the commands generate series of errors: `! Undefined control sequence.`

The reason why I am trying to scale the whole picture is `scale=0.5` while defining environment `tizkpicture` also does not work.

The example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[landscape,margin=0.5cm,a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calendar}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\newcommand{\calrow}[1]{\node[anchor=base east](lun){l};
\node[base right=of lun](mar){m}; \node[base right=of mar](mer){m};
\node[base right=of mer](gio){g}; \node[base right=of gio](ven){v};
\node[base right=of ven](sab){s}; \node[base right=of sab](dom){d};
\node[darkgreen,above=of gio]{\textbf{#1}};}

\newcommand{\calperiod}[1]{\calendar[dates=\the\year-#1-01 to \the\year-#1-last]
if(Sunday) [black!50] \holidays;}

\newcommand{\holidays}{% holidays in Italy
if (equals=01-01) [black!50]%
if (equals=01-06) [black!50]%
if (equals=04-04) [black!50]%
if (equals=04-05) [black!50]%
if (equals=04-25) [black!50]%
if (equals=05-01) [black!50]%
if (equals=05-01) [black!50]%
if (equals=06-02) [black!50]%
if (equals=08-15) [black!50]%
if (equals=11-01) [black!50]%
if (equals=12-08) [black!50]%
if (equals=12-25) [black!50]%
if (equals=12-26) [black!50]%
}

\colorlet{darkgreen}{green!50!black}

\begin{document}

\null
\vfill

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every calendar/.style={week list}]
        \sffamily
        \matrix[row 1/.style={darkgreen, node distance=.3ex}, row 3/.style={darkgreen, node distance=.3ex}, column sep=1ex, draw=darkgreen,thick,rounded corners=5pt, postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.51 with {\node[fill=white,text=darkgreen,font={\bfseries\Large}] (year) {\the\year};}}}]
        {%
            % first row: week day and month
            \calrow{January} & \calrow{February} & \calrow{March} &
            \calrow{April} & \calrow{May} & \calrow{June} \\
            
            % second row: calendar
            \calperiod{01} & \calperiod{02} & \calperiod{03} &
            \calperiod{04} & \calperiod{05} & \calperiod{06} \\[1ex]
            
            % third row: week day and month
            \calrow{July} & \calrow{August} & \calrow{September} &
            \calrow{October} & \calrow{November} & \calrow{December} \\
            % forth row: calendar
            \calperiod{07} & \calperiod{08} & \calperiod{09} &
            \calperiod{10} & \calperiod{11} & \calperiod{12} \\
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\vfill

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TewX.SX! I think that you are following Martin Scharrer's answer from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/562483/error-using-resizebox-and-tikz. He actually gives three alternatives, the last of which is to use [adjustbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox). Using this solves your problem: `\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}\end{adjustbox}`

Comment: Hi. Yes, using `adjustbox` environment works for me, which scales everything inside the `tikz`, which is what I needed. Thanks!